# Why in the following code, Father always goes below %mother?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want that "Father is over mother". Why in the following code, Father always goes below mother?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\newlength\treeheight
\setlength{\treeheight}{\textheight-2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right,anchor=west,
  every node/.style={},
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/2},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/4},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/8}]
  % parents
  \node {My Family Tree}[edge from parent fork right]
    child { node {Father}
      child{ node {Paternal Gfather}
        child{ node {Paternal GGfather}}
        child{ node {Paternal GGmother}}
      }
      child{ node {Paternal Gmother}
        child{ node {Maternal GGfather}}
        child{ node {Maternal GGmother}}
      }
    }
    child { node {Mother}
      child{ node {Maternal Gfather}}
      child{ node {Maternal Gmother}}
    }

  ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Change `grow=right` by `grow'=right` and father will move over mother. Why? It's explained in section "21.5.2 Default Growth Function" from pgfmanual.

Comment: I'd suggest to delete [your previous version of same question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224345/why-in-the-following-code-father-always-goes-below-mother?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Ignasi, you should use `grow'=right` instead of `grow right`. `grow'`, when used, arranges the children in the opposite order. Further, you may like to add some `inner sep`aration to all nodes and split long nodes using `align=left` as I did. I have also adjusted the `level distance` in the code to adjust the distance between levels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\newlength\treeheight
\setlength{\treeheight}{\textheight-2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=right,anchor=west,
  every node/.style={align=left,inner sep=4pt},
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/2},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/4},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=\treeheight/8}]
  % parents
  \node[anchor=east] {My Family\\ Tree}[edge from parent fork right,level distance=1in]
    child { node {Father}
      child{ node {Paternal\\ Gfather}
        child{ node {Paternal\\ GGfather}}
        child{ node {Paternal\\ GGmother}}
      }
      child{ node {Paternal\\ Gmother}
        child{ node {Maternal\\ GGfather}}
        child{ node {Maternal\\ GGmother}}
      }
    }
    child { node {Mother}
      child{ node {Maternal\\ Gfather}}
      child{ node {Maternal\\ Gmother}}
    }

  ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]